# Sinch iOS Conference call record via AVAudioSession

Tags: ios, avaudiosession, sinch

Could some one help me please with Sinch conference call recording via AVAudioSession?

Answer (score 0):

you can record on the server by adding record:true in the ice request. please contact to support to enable recording.